# Need to build a foreach statement from a hash array of variable elements in Perl

Tags: xml, arrays, perl, hash, foreach

I'm using `XML::Simple` in Perl to parse through an XML file and I'm stuck on how to build a loop to go through all the possible elements of an array within the hash.

Here's how to print the 0th element of the array:

```
print $book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}[0]->{is_new};
```

My terminology might be off when using the words hash vs. array, but I'm trying to loop through all of the elements within `{Price}[$ref]`

I tried:

```
my @refs = $book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price};
foreach(@refs)
{
    print $book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}[$_]->{store_id};
    print "\n";
}
```

and

```
foreach my $key (keys (%{$book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}}))
{
    print $key."\n";
}
```

This next print statement returns a value of `"ARRAY(0x159a57c)"`

```
   print [$book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}];
```

---

This works for the foreach, but I can't access the elements correctly:

```
foreach (@{$book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}})
{
    print $book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}[$_]; #this line is wrong
}
```

Any suggestions?  There are multiple `{Price}` elements within the `{Prices}` element, and each `{Price}` element has `[x]` attributes in the XML.

Comment: I haven't used XML::Simple, but I would presume that `$book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}` is array ref, so you will need to dereference it like this `@( $book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price})`. Also include the output you get now from your script.

Comment: i tried `foreach (@($book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}))` and got `Scalar found where operator expected.....`

Comment: Take a look at [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People aren't quite getting it right for you.  If I understand you correctly, you want:

```
foreach my $element ( @{ $book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price} } ) {
    print $element->{store_id};
    print "\n";
}
```

Helpful advice for dealing with nested data structures can be found at http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: i tried the same, but i want to get at these elements: `print $book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}[$element];`  ill look through that site now

Comment: `print $book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}[$element]->{store_id};`

Comment: #4 from the site: `${$hRef->{KEY}}[1]  $hRef->{KEY}->[1]  $hRef->{KEY}[1]` looks the closest to my situation, but not sure how it might fit in

Comment: i didn't fully understand your answer till just now... haha thanks - that works!

Answer (score 2):

Marginally extending [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth)'s answer:

```
foreach my $elem_ref (@{$book_info->{BookList}->{BookData}->{Prices}->{Price}})
{
    foreach my $key (sort keys %{$elem_ref})
    {
        print $elem_ref->{$key};
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

In part, this uses the recommendation from Perl Best Practices to denote references with the suffix `_ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try dumping the contents of $book_info with Data::Dumper (use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($book_info)? It should give you a clue on how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe you could post an output here so we could take a look.